# Does Samsung Galaxy Tab 3(SM-T211) have radio facility?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-3-7

I purchased Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 (Model SM-T211) and I am searching for Radio in the Home Menu. Does the Tab 3 have radio functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say this but this facility is not there..!!

Answer (score 1):

I own a SM-T211 myself. **There is no built in radio functionality for this device.**

However, you can install internet-based radio apps from Play Store. Hope it helps.

As a side note, a quick search for the Galaxy Tab product line on PhoneArena reveals that none of them, starting from the first to the fourth generation tablets, have radio functionality.